# J-Carousel Code Missing?

Tags: javascript, slider

By accident, I managed to delete/remove something from the code for the homepage carousel. I have re-built so code so far so a banner will now appear on the homepage, but the banner does not scroll. The buttons at the bottom of the banner are there, but I am unable to click on them to access the other banners on the carousel.

```
<div class="banners">
    <div class="pager jcarousel-control"><a href="#">1</a><a href="#">2</a><a href="#">3</a><a href="#">4</a><a href="#">5</a><a href="#">6</a><a href="#">7</a><a href="#">8</a><a href="#">9</a><a href="#">10</a><a href="#">11</a></div>
     <div class="holder">
     <ul>
         [...]
```

Am I missing something basic from the above code that I need to include to active the carousel scroll?

Any help would be hugely hugely appreciated.

***Edit from OP mispost***

There is back-up/help-sheets for all other coding issues for the homepage but nothing for the carousel. The homepage of the website is www.cmsplc.com, you will be able to see the first banner and the buttons at the bottom, these buttons do not function and the carousel doesn't scroll automatically. Is there any code missing?

Comment: can't you get the code from a backup? if not, do you get any js errors?

Comment: Right now the carousel is running when I look at the site. Also the dom structure doesn't have a `<div class="banners">` element there. What isn not there and what isn't working?